# Unnable to acces other drives and partition due to insuficent permissions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, macosx

I have a Dell Inspiron 15r running both Ubuntu 13.10 and OS X mountain lion. I was trying to change my Ubuntu UID to 501 co I could read and write in the OS X home folder without root permissions.

Now when I try to access the partition it tells that I don’t have the permissions necessary to view the contents of the partition. It does the same thing for other drives that I use.

I need an answer fast because school starts in two days.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [thread over on Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1878310) that while old, basically covers how to recover from your scenario. You'll want to return your Ubuntu uid back to its original value, which should be 1000 with `sudo usermod -u 1000 your_username`

[This thread on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write) has some options for mounting the Mac partition as read/write, though there may be some issues with having to either disabling journaling on the Mac partition or only having root-level access to it. You might be able to get it to mount with the correct uid with an entry in `fstab` but I have never seen instructions for mounting HFS+ partitions via `fstab`.